# Google Play Games (Leaderboard): Get Best score from yesterday

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard

Is it possible with Google Play Games to find out the 1st place from yesterday in leaderboard?

Now it is only possible to find out the best score from today, weekly or all-time.
The Daily leaderboards reset at midnight PST every day, and weekly leaderboards reset at Saturday midnight PST.

I would like to show the best player from the last day in a notification. It is possible only with Google Play Games?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trick would be to create a leaderboard for each day. Now you read always the leaderboard from yesterday with weekly parameter.